# About vulnerability in the dependency

Tags: php, javascript, vulnerability, java, python

I have read many articles about the vulnerability in the program dependency, either direct or transitive.

Here are two questions come out of my mind.

1. If a dependency A has a vulnerability (Maybe has a CVE identifier) in one of its function called foo(), and I include this dependency A in my application. If my code doesn't call the foo() function, will my program still be vulnerable? I know it is language specific, so what will happen if this situation happens in python or javascript or Java or PHP?
2. Are vulnerabilities in development dependency (Example: DevDependencies listed in package.json for Javascript) actually matter? I have read some posts, some said yes, while others said no. I know that it is not a problem for end user if the deployed application doesn't include those development dependency, but are those vulnerabilities in the development dependency actually exploitable for the developer who is using those development dependencies in development phase? For language like python/javascript/java/php?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question, it is very hard to tell for sure that a vulnerability will not affect you. Even if you don't explicitly call the vulnerable function, maybe some function you call does. Maybe som developer will call it in the future. Maybe your program does not call it when given normal input, but a clever attacker can make the program call it. Maybe the vulnerability is bigger than first though, and also affect other functions.

In some cases, you may be able to make an educated quess that you are not affected. If the library is an image processing library, the vulnerability is in the JPG processing library, and you have hardcoded it to only handle PNG images, then maybe you are safe. Maybe. Or an attacker manage to trick the library to run the JPG code paths anyway, and you are screwed.

To say that you have a high confidence that you are not affected, you need to have a deep understanding of both the vulnerability and your own application. Caution is adviced, and when possible err on the side of safety.

As for your second questions, a vulnerability in the dev dependencies might be used to exploit the developer. That is off course a bad thing.

Sometimes vulnerability reports include vulnerabilities in your dev dependencys dependencies. It is not obvious that these will be exploitable in your dev environment. But on the other hand, it is not obvious that they are not. Again, there is no clear cut answer or fast rule. An understanding of the individual vulnerability is needed to assess the risk.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unknown, but it could be either vulnerable or not. You cannot rely on the description alone to determine why foo() was vulnerable. Perhaps foo() relies on an internal function like parseJson() that actually contains the vulnerability; bar() may also use parseJson(), but pen testers never found the vulnerability, or it’s vulnerable in a slightly different way. The vendor may not even realize the scope of the patch, or they may not publicize all the details in order to obscure the scope of the vulnerability in an attempt to defer related attacks. You shouldn’t trust the dependency until it’s patched.
2. Yes, they matter. As of the date of this answer (mid-2021) prominent waves of attacks are “supply chain attacks”.  Attackers are constantly searching for ways to embed their malware into the development process. A recent example is the SolarWinds attack, which used a breach in the product’s development process to inject a hidden back door in their Orion product, allowing attackers access to hundreds or thousands of SolarWinds’ clients.

Bottom line: if a vulnerability is announced on a product that’s in your org, patch — don’t waste time or effort making up excuses to not patch. If it isn’t already, it should be part of your organization’s security policy to keep your systems patched on a timely basis.